# Remove unnecessary part of a filename in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm sorry, I know this is a noob question, but I've researched for more than 5 hours now and can't figure out how to achieve what I want.

I have a folder with lots files in the form of:

"Artist - Song Tttle (ft. Ruth B) (Prod. Blulake)-28GpKacWLWI.mp4"
"Some other Artist - Song Tittle [HD]-ZN9cJvl-P4c.mp4"
"DNMO & Sub Urban - Broken (Official Lyric Video)-KZT-_VW-k38.mp4"

And I want to rename them all to:
"Artist - Song Tttle (ft. Ruth B) (Prod. Blulake).mp4"
"Some other Artist - Song Tittle [HD].mp4"
"DNMO & Sub Urban - Broken (Official Lyric Video).mp4"

Please help!

Comment: Well perhaps you made a minor mistake, what have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this is going to depend on how consistent your file names are but essentially looping over all the files in the directory and renaming them should work. Something like:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\whereever
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
                $name = $file.name
                $ext = $file.extension
                $parts = $name -split '-'
                $newname = $parts[0] + "-" + $parts[1] + $ext
                Rename-Item -Path $name -NewName $newname
}
dir
```

You might want to wrap it in a conditional to only affect certain filetypes etc.

-- I wrote this on my phone. I have not tested it.

Comment: @NikolaArmyanov My Pleasure. Best of luck.